# Refused to load blob:https://xxx.xxx because it doesn't appear in frame-ancestors directive of content security policy

Tags: javascript, safari

I have implemented PDF Print functionality using below code snippet. This is working well in all other browsers except Safari. Over safari I see **Refused to load blob:https://xxx.xxx because it doesn't appear in frame-ancestors directive of content security policy** error.

```
`const pdfstr = await fetch(`data:application/pdf;base64,${terms}`)
    const blobFromFetch = await pdfstr.blob()
    var blob = new Blob([blobFromFetch], { type: 'application/pdf' })
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    let iFrame = document.createElement('iframe')
    iFrame.src = blobUrl
    iFrame.style.display = 'none'
    iFrame.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            iFrame.focus()
            iFrame.contentWindow.print()
            setTimeout(() => {
                iFrame.parentNode.removeChild(iFrame)
            }, 20000)
        }, 1)
    }
    document.body.appendChild(iFrame)
```

`
I tried replacing iFrame with object and embed but it didn't work out. Tried with couple of other solutions as well but no luck.